# PSQL - IF CONDITION for DO UPDATE

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently using the following query to update my PSQL table:

```sql
INSERT INTO table(key, value, value_first_seen) VALUES ('test', 'value', '2022-04-14 20:50:23.02858+00') 
                ON CONFLICT (key) DO 
                UPDATE
                SET key = excluded.key;
```

I would like to also update `value_first_seen` only if the `value` column has changed.

I want to achieve something like the query below, but was not able to find any solutions:

```sql
INSERT INTO table(key, value, value_first_seen) VALUES ('test', 'value', '2022-04-14 20:50:23.02858+00') 
                ON CONFLICT (key) DO 
                UPDATE
                SET value = excluded.value
                IF value != excluded.value SET value_first_seen = excluded.value_first_seen;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` to choose.

```
INSERT INTO table(key, value, value_first_seen) VALUES ('test', 'value', '2022-04-14 20:50:23.02858+00') 
                ON CONFLICT (key) DO 
                UPDATE
                SET key = excluded.key,
                    value_first_seen = case
                       when value != excluded.value then
                         excluded.value_first_seen
                       else
                         value_first_seen
                       end,
                    value = excluded.value;
```